# How long would it take a projectile accelerating twice as fast as another to catch up?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

Given a projectile with initial velocity $u$, and constant acceleration $a$, travelling in the one direction. How long would it take a second projectile the same as the first with the same initial velocity $u$ and twice the acceleration $2a$ but launched after the first by $t$ amount of time?

I thought I could do this by calculating the displacement of the first projectile travels after time $t$: $s$. Then take the difference in acceleration $2a - a = a$, and find how long it would take for the second projectile to travel $s$ and that would be the answer?

OK so I know to calculate the displacement at time t I need the final velocity at time $t$: $v$. $v$ can be found by:

$$v = u + at$$

then $s$:

$$s = ut + \frac{1}{2}{at^2}$$

Now I have the displacement of the first projectile after time $t$ I simply need to find the time the second projectile will take to travel $s$, but how can I find that? (I do not know what the second projectiles final velocity will be when it travels $s$...

Comment: Your question is most likely to be closed if you don't show your effort on the given question.

Comment: OK, I have given what I think will work, but I do not know the answer so do not know.

Comment: You're getting there. What you want is to have a function for the displacement of each projectile in terms of time. Once you do that, you can equate the two functions to find the time at which their displacements are equal. Given their accelerations and initial velocities, can you come up with a function to describe the displacement of each projectile as a function of time?

Comment: Now, the discussion is going on in PSE meta about completely banning homework questions.Now, the site is looking for standard homework questions and I think that asking about the concept involved in the question will draw more attention to this question.

Comment: I did not tag it as homework, someone else did, I am a game developer rusty on my physics and re-learning as I need to.

Comment: Hi markmnl. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: You do not actually need the final velocity of a projectile to describe its position at time t. In one dimension, the displacement $s$ of a projectile with constant acceleration at time $t$ is given by $s(t) = s_0 + v_0t + \frac{at^2}{2}$, where $s_0$ is the initial displacement of the projectile from your origin, $v_0$ is the initial velocity of the object, and $a$ is the constant acceleration the object is undergoing.

Comment: OK, I see the tag is appropriate and have updated my question with what I have tried but now am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're overloading your time variable.  Let the *delay* of the launch of the 2nd projectile be $t_d$ while the time variable is $t$.

As you've already correctly written, the equation for the displacement of the 1st projectile is (for $t \ge 0$):

$$s_1 = ut + \dfrac{at^2}{2}$$

Now, for the 2nd projection, we have (for $t' \ge 0$):

$$s_2 = ut' + \dfrac{2at'^2}{2} = ut' + at'^2$$

where

$$t' = t - t_d$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: well I want the time when $s1$ = $s2$, so after calculating $s1$ I can sub it for $s2$ in the equation and $t'$ becomes the only unknown which I can then work out! thanks

Comment: is my comment correct?

Comment: @markmnl, if your comment is essentially *set the equation for s1 equal to the equation for s2 and solve for t* then yes, your comment is correct.

Comment: @markmnl, please note my edit of the equation for s2.  I had neglected to account for the fact that the 2nd projectile has twice the acceleration of the 1st.

Comment: therefore $t'$ = ($u$ - $s$)/$a$, that's great